# REGEX recursion for table name extraction from a SQL Query when comma is used instead of CROSS JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I am aware that a proper SQL Parser is a better solution. However, my aim is to learn how to leverage a recursion pattern of Regex.

Imagine these exemplary queries that are all exactly the same:

- `SELECT a.x, b.y FROM table_1 AS a, table_2 AS b WHERE a.id = b.id`
- `SELECT a.x, b.y FROM table_1 a, table_2 b WHERE a.id = b.id`
- `SELECT table_1.x, table_2.y FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.id`
- `SELECT table_1.x, b.y FROM table_1, table_2 AS b WHERE table_1.id = b.id`

We can have three cross joins too:

- `SELECT table_1.x, b.y FROM table_1, table_2 AS b, table_3 WHERE table_1.id = b.id AND b.id = table_3.id`

### Question:

**How can we have a Regex that can extract the table names in such mode of doing CROSS JOIN?**

In first set of 4 examples, the output should be `[table_1, table_2]`

I am trying to wrap my head around on whether and how the **`(?R)`** recursive pattern can be used to do so? Or maybe I don't need it ?

> PS: I think the recursion should continue until we see one of the keywords of: `ON|WHERE|GROUP BY|LIMIT`

Comment: Extract a substring between FROM and WHERE (excluding both keywords). Remove everything between AS and comma (storing the comma).

Comment: Fast variant: https://dbfiddle.uk/aDDgEuYT Fails on: quoted tablenames with space, subqueries, JOINs and so on.

Comment: These are great @Akina, but I would still like to learn about the `(?R)` pattern in REGEX as well.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: SQL (to be more precise, the Presto engine). We can assume that Regex-capability is good (i.e., it supports (?R) construct).